# Application of derivatives and darboux principle

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Calculus have its own way to teach which inspires me a lot. I am stuck at this confusion , Let $f$ be a real valued function such that $f$ is continuous in $[0,2]$ and differentiable in $(0,2)$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f(2)=2$. Then there exists $c \in (0,2)$ such that a) $f'(c)= 1$, b) $f'(c)= 0.4$, c) $f'(c) =0$,      d) $f'(c)= 2$? . Which of them are correct? Using Mean value theorem, a is correct. Now we have Darbaux principle according to which if $I$ be a closed interval, $f : I \to \mathbb R$ a real-valued differentiable function, then $f'$ has the intermediate value property: if $a$ and $b$ are points in $I$ with $a < b$, then for every $y$ between $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$ there exists an $x \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(x)= y$. But since $f$ is not differentiable in $[0,2]$ I am confused; how can we use Darbaux principle here?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Do we have any information on the values of $f(a)$ and $f(b)$?

Answer (score 1):

All of the four options can be false, as the function $f(x)=3x$ demonstrates.

---

After you added the condition, yes, (a) is correct.

The other three options can all still be false, as the function $f(x)=x$ demonstrates.

Comment: I have added one more condition

Comment: @alearner I edited my answer.

Comment: And if I replace condition f(2)= 2 by f(2)=1 then we can use darbaux?

Comment: f'(c)=\frac12$. Means ?

Comment: @alearner I meant to write $f'(x)=\frac12$.

Comment: So what happens when I replace that f(2)=2 condition by =1 ? Please tell sir

Comment: @alearner Then you will have $f'(c)=0$, obviously.

Comment: @alearner I advise you re-read the chapter or discuss it with your teacher.

Comment: Okay sir,I do  re- read chapter and discuss it with my teacher but please tell me one thing if we have conditions like f(0)=0,  f(1)=1 , f(2)=1 then which option is correct

Comment: @alearner I will not. You seem to treat me as a machine where you plug in values and questions, and I spit out answers. And I don't like that, and it's also not what this site is about. This site is about learning and understanding, and right now, you don't seem to want to do any of that. You just want your results.

Comment: Sir,actually I was not trying to get result but how we can apply darboux principle in that situation. But sorry for what I had done unintentionally